# Disabling dynamically genereted bootstrap buttons in mvc view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to disable all the buttons in my view when my ajax call returns true, but everything i tried so far didn't work :

```
 @model IEnumerable<eksp.Models.WorkRole>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "DisplayListOfRolesUser";
    }
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var dataJSON;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("checkNumRoles", "WorkRoles")',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: successFunc,
                    error: errorFunc
                });

                function successFunc(data, status) {



                    if (data== true) {

                        $(".btn").prop('disabled', true);
                    }
                    alert(data);
                }

                function errorFunc() {
                    alert('error');
                }


            });


    </script>



    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoleName)</h1>
            <p class="lead">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoleDescription)</p>
            <p> @Html.ActionLink(">Focus on this one!", "addWorkRoleUser", new { id = item.WorkRoleId },  new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg" })</p>
        </div>        

    }
```

Whate i tried so far is :

```
$('.btn').addClass('btn-disabled');
$('.btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('.btn').prop('disabled', true);
```

I don't get why this won't work. Probably I am missing something very small, but I don't know what.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you place a breakpoint (or an alert) in your `successFunc` to make sure you are receiving the correct value of the correct data type?

Comment: Also, your if statement references a variable whose assignment is commented out.

Comment: I am receiving the correct value. Also the i just commented out the variable before posting here. So this isn't the problem.

Comment: posting defunct code here does no one any good.

Comment: You have a point. I will correct it now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use disabled class to disable button.

```
$('.btn').addClass('disabled');
```